# jQuery only works by selecting the ID, not the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I tried to do an event listener, in my case with "keyup" to count the entered elements.

Everything works when I link the message-box with its ID, like so:

```
$("#message-box-1").on("keyup", function() {...
```

but when I link the class, like so:

```
$(".message-box").on("keyup", function() {...
```

the counter doesn't work anymore.

I had a similar problem before where I had to use the ID instead of the class, because otherwise the function wouldn't work...

Comment: can you share some HTML and code?

Comment: Could you include your HTML?

Comment: share html mark up as well

Comment: check if same class is actually there, as I see it seems okay

Comment: This is not a jquery or any general problem, it must be in the way you scripted it. jQuery is able to select by class always, as same as by id.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/julian1605/bb916b7116508b3a746d2055dc2c510a

This is an extract, that is correctly displayed in the console as long as I link the ID

Answer (score 2):

you have two classes

```
 <textarea style="resize:none" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control" class="message-box" id="message-box-1" title="Please enter a message" required="required" placeholder="Your message here"></textarea>
```

please remove as jquery will ignore second attribute with same name or merge with same class attribute

```
 <textarea style="resize:none" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control message-box" id="message-box-1" title="Please enter a message" required="required" placeholder="Your message here"></textarea>
```

Comment: Might want to make it clear you *can* have 2 classes, but in the same attribute - `class="form-control message-box"`

Comment: Oh yes, that seems obvious!
I tried it out, and it works!!! :)  Thank you very much for your help!